# BizTalk mapping records into pairs

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Using a BizTalk Map and wondering if there's a good way to do the following.

I need to map a received Invoice to a list of Orders. However each Order must contain only two line items (let's assume the Invoice has an even number).

This means that Invoice(1, 2, 3, 4) should map to Orders(Order (1, 2), Order (3, 4)).

Essentially, I need to create new parent elements when `(index % 2 == 0)`.

Is there a **functoid-only** way of doing this?

XML example below:

```
<Invoice>
  <Client>Client1</Client>
  <Line>
    <Code>1</Code>
    <Price>$1.00</Price>
    <Qty>1</Qty>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Code>2</Code>
    <Price>$2.00</Price>
    <Qty>2</Qty>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Code>3</Code>
    <Price>$3.00</Price>
    <Qty>3</Qty>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Code>4</Code>
    <Price>$4.00</Price>
    <Qty>4</Qty>
  </Line>
</Invoice>
```

to

```
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <Client>Client1</Client>
    <OrderItem>
      <Code>1</Code>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
      <Code>2</Code>
      <Qty>2</Qty>
    </OrderItem>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <Client>Client1</Client>
    <OrderItem>
      <Code>3</Code>
      <Qty>3</Qty>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
      <Code>4</Code>
      <Qty>4</Qty>
    </OrderItem>  
   </Order>
</Orders>
```

**What I've tried:**

- Standard mapping: A single Order with all lines, as expected
- Value Mapping to *Client* based on `index % 2`: Order per line (half have *Client*)
- Table Looping (Gated to `index % 2`) + Extractor to *Client*: Order per line, only half lines

**What I'm likely to end up doing:**

- XSLT
- Or, C# manipulation after mapping

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't even try and use the mapper to do this. I would instead use straight XSLT.

Comment: I second Nick's comment. xslt is not difficult and will do the job easily.

Comment: XSLT maintainability is usually a pretty big barrier to client adoption, but I'll agree when it's needed it's needed. Just a pity this kind of thing isn't supported out of the box.

Comment: I got partway there with a map.  From Line, a iteration functiod a Modula with 2, a equals sign with 0 linked too Order.  This will create two orders with one line each of 2 and 4.

Answer (score -1):

In the advanced functoids section of the toolbox look for the 'index' functoid.
Add a scripting functoid on the output.
Add C# code to check for the indexes you want to match.
You can switch output on and off by returning a boolean from the scripting functoid.